# sum of specific key for multiple similar keys in array of object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like the following:

```
[
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 150,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 100,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 200,
        'Location': 2,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 10,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 130,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P3',
        'Price': 40,
        'Location': 1,
    }
]
```

I need to add up all the prices for objects with the **same product and same location**.  For the example above the result would be:

```
[
   {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 250, // price is the sum of both similar in location and product
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 200,
        'Location': 2, // same product but different location
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 140, //sum of same
        'Location': 1, 
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P3',
        'Price': 40,
        'Location': 1,
    },
]
```

I have searched several similar issues, but those were dealing with only one key to check for, I have different keys (product and location - may be more than 2 in the future) to identify as different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = [
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 150,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 100,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 200,
        'Location': 2,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 10,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 130,
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P3',
        'Price': 40,
        'Location': 1,
    }
]

const output = []
input.forEach(item => {
  const index = output.findIndex(o => o.Product === item.Product && o.Location === item.Location);
  if (index === -1) {
    output.push(item);
  } else {
    output[index].Price += item.Price;
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

---

Without arrow function

```
input.forEach(function(item) {
  const index = output.findIndex(function(o) { return o.Product === item.Product && o.Location === item.Location});
  if (index === -1) {
    output.push(item);
  } else {
    output[index].Price += item.Price;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce() to do that,

```js
obj = [
   {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 250, // price is the sum of both similar in location and product
        'Location': 1,
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P1',
        'Price': 200,
        'Location': 2, // same product but different location
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P2',
        'Price': 140, //sum of same
        'Location': 1, 
    },
    {
        'Product': 'P3',
        'Price': 40,
        'Location': 1,
    },
]

res = obj.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  index = prev.findIndex(item => item.Product=== curr.Product && item.Location === curr.Location);
  if(index > -1) {
    prev[index].Price += curr.Price;
  } else {
    prev.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @William's answer (Accepted) for my use case as it was to be run on the platform which was not supporting ES6 features (`findIndex` and arrow function), this can be done without `findIndex` as below;

```js
var input = [{
    'Product': 'P1',
    'Price': 150,
    'Location': 1,
  },
  {
    'Product': 'P1',
    'Price': 100,
    'Location': 1,
  },
  {
    'Product': 'P1',
    'Price': 200,
    'Location': 2,
  },
  {
    'Product': 'P2',
    'Price': 10,
    'Location': 1,
  },
  {
    'Product': 'P2',
    'Price': 130,
    'Location': 1,
  },
  {
    'Product': 'P3',
    'Price': 40,
    'Location': 1,
  }
]

var output = []
input.forEach(function(item) {
  var index = output.indexOf(output.filter(function(o) {
    return o.Product === item.Product && o.Location === item.Location
  })[0]); // note the [0] index here
  if (index === -1) {
    output.push(item);
  } else {
    output[index].Price += item.Price;
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: there is a button that reads  "Tidy" inside the snippet editor that formats your code - please use that after you finish editing your snippet. (it's right below "save and insert post" button)